# Azure-AD OIDC: Any Logging Available?

Tags: azure-active-directory, passport.js, openid-connect, passport-azure-ad

Where do I find logging on why there was a failure on an Azure-AD OpenId Connect login?

I've created an application under:
Portal.Azure.com -> Azure AD -> App Registrations

And created a key for the said application under the same location, "Keys".

I'm attempting to use passport-azure-ad to authenticate to the end-point and have it mostly working, but I believe I need more additional server-side logging details to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Currently, I successfully am redirected by my applcation to the following location where I am given an option to login:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

When I successfully login, I get:

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

We received a bad request.
```

I'm assuming there must be some logging somewhere to tell me more details on what is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently I did not notice the details at the bottom of the error page referenced above, in itty bitty print.

In my specific situation this included:

```
Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 891cdfd8-9aa1-4f8b-a538-9accdd9705f7
Timestamp: 2016-10-14 16:38:37Z
AADSTS70001: Application '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' is not supported for this API version.
```

Why I'm getting this, I still don't understand; but that isn't really my original question anyway. I also imagine that these details, or additional details are logged somewhere else and it would be helpful to know where they are.

As a result I'm leaving this open to see if anyone has a better answer.

Comment: Apps registered at portal.azure.com won't work with the v2.0 endpoint.  Please see aka.ms/aadv2 for info on how to register an app.

Comment: I seem to be being told conflicting things:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088260/create-application-with-authenticates-against-o365-azure-ad-with-openidconnect unless there is a way to do OIDC without v2.0

Comment: There is! See aka.ms/aaddev. And notice there is a difference between the URL you're using and the one I recommend in the other post