# Create Application with Authenticates against O365 Azure AD with OpenIdConnect

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I've got an application I'm creating for use with Office 365 accounts (Will be multi-tenant). I'm looking to use OpenID Connect for authentication. I do not need regular Microsoft accounts working.

I've tried creating an application at:
https://portal.azure.com -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations

As well as:
https://manage.windowsazure.com -> Active Directory -> Applications

These did not appear to work for OpenId Connect.

Creating an app at:
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Did work for OpenId Connect.

Can someone please help advise:

1. What's the difference between these different URL's?
2. Is it possible to get OpenID Connect running from an app registered on one of the Azure sites so that all my Azure stuff is centralized?

Comment: Apps registered in Azure AD, regardless of which portal you used to register, support OpenID Connect. Can you share the code which is not working, as well as the specific error message you receive?

Comment: Application '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' is not supported for this API version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new app in https://portal.azure.com there is no service principal created for you in your local tenant. When you do the first authorize request to your app, the service principal gets created in your local AD tenant. See http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/10/04/provision-an-app-created-on-portal-azure-com-in-your-own-tenant/ for more infromation.

If you create an app using the classic portal, both the application object and the service principal are created.

To verify your issue I created a new app using the modern portal, https://portal.azure.com, and opened

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={application_id}
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7
```

in a browser while having fiddler running in the background.

Note: replace `{tenant}`, `{application_id}` and the `redirect_uri` with your Azure AD tenant id (guid) and your application ID (also a guid). `state` and `nonce` are required but can have any value.

When you open the URL in a browser, it will first ask the user to consent the app, and if successful make a postback to the redirect_uri with id_token.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code/ for more information on doing OpenID Connect requests.

You can also create a new app using https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. You should use this page to register new apps if you want to take advantage of the v2.0 endpoint and authentication protocol. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-limitations/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there are two different OpenID Connect endpoints you need to choose from.  If you don't require Microsoft accounts, I recommend you register an app at portal.azure.com, and use the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` endpoint for performing OIDC.  There is good protocol documentation and code samples available at aka.ms/aaddev

Comment: That is exactly what I did to get the error, " 
Application '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' is not supported for this API version."